# Table Binding Modification

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this data set with patient information/charges (Table 1).

I am looking to achieve Table 3. Table 3 shown below has:

- Distinct Patient Number (Patno)
- The sum of Billed Charges for each Patno (sum billed charges then
  group by patno)
- DRG Rate from Table 2. This is just matching the DRG in Table 1 to
  Table 2 and getting the DRG Rate Associated with it.
- Stop loss column. If the sum of Billed Charges for a patient (found
  in column 2) is >275000 then (SUM of Billed Charges    -275000)*.195+
  DRG Rate from column 3
- Claim total: If there is a stop loss, then the claim total is just
  = to the stop loss value found in column 4. ELSE, it is equal to the DRG rate.

Note, each patient has only ONE claim, but can have
multiple line items as shown in table 1.

Table 1: [BCBS$] (This is the raw data)

[image]

Table 2: [BCDRG] (DRG Lookup Table)

[image]

Table 3: Result Table

[image]

My Code Right Now:
**Note I have SUM(AMT), it's the same as Billed Charges**

```
SELECT PATNO, SUM([AMT]) as AMT,
BCDRG.[DRG Rate], 

CASE WHEN SUM([AMT]) >275000 THEN ((SUM([AMT])-275000 )*.195)+BCDRG.[DRG Rate] ELSE 'NO' END AS StopLoss,
CASE WHEN SUM([AMT]) >275000 THEN ((SUM([AMT])-275000 )*.195)+BCDRG.[DRG Rate] ELSE BCDRG.[DRG Rate] END AS ClaimTotal
FROM [BCBS$] AS RD
INNER JOIN [BCDRG] AS DR ON RD.DRG=DR.[DRG Code]

GROUP BY PATNO
```

The errors I am getting:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 45
The multi-part identifier "BCDRG.DRG Rate" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 47
The multi-part identifier "BCDRG.DRG Rate" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 48
The multi-part identifier "BCDRG.DRG Rate" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 48
The multi-part identifier "BCDRG.DRG Rate" could not be bound.
```

I am assuming my join is off? From my research it seems this error is when it can't locate the tables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you alias a table you can then only use that alias to reference the table, you can no longer use the table name. So anything `BCDRG.` should now be `DR.`.

Comment: Thanks! I will be sure to remember that going forward. Fixed all the binding errors and the only error I am getting now is ```Column 'BCDRG.DRG Rate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.``` So basically I need to wrap my DR.DRG RATE in my select statement in an aggregate function or I can't have it I am assuming?

Comment: If you want to aggregate in your query, all your resulting columns must either be grouped by or aggregated. If you consider that carefully, because otherwise how would SQL Server know which value to show you when multiple rows are being aggregated?

Comment: Makes sense, thank you sir!